# Turn blivesta animsition menu into off canvas (push body) menu

Tags: jquery, css, html, drawer, animsition

The menu works fine, but the menu overlays my content and i would like to see that it's pushing my content to the right, like an off-canvas menu.

Edit: The inside anchor problem is solved here (thanks to @polamoros): 
[Scroll to top after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657199/scroll-to-top-after-click)

My question, is this possible in a few simple steps?

I tried to make a JSFiddle but couldnt get it done unfortunately.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Mobile Menu -->

<link href="nav/sandbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="nav/drawer.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Mobile Menu -->

</head>

<body class="drawer drawer--left">
<?php include("mobile_menu.php");?>

<div class="container">
<p> My content </p>
</div>

<?php include("footer.php");?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iScroll/5.1.3/iscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ungki/bootstrap.dropdown/3.3.5/dropdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="nav/drawer.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.drawer').drawer();
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/*!------------------------------------*\
    Base
\*!------------------------------------*/
.drawer-nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d7f8fd;
}

.drawer-brand {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3.75rem;
  display: block;
  padding-right: .75rem;
  padding-left: .75rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}

.drawer-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.drawer-list-item {
  padding: 0;
}

.drawer-menu-header{
  background-color: #d7f8fd;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  padding: .75rem .75rem .75rem 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c9ebf0;
  color: #999;
}

.drawer-menu-item {
background-color: #d7f8fd;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  padding: .75rem .75rem .75rem 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c9ebf0;
  color: #222;
}

.drawer-menu-item:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: #e6fbfe;
  color: #555;
}

/*! overlay */
.drawer-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.drawer-open .drawer-overlay {
  display: block;
}
/*!------------------------------------*\
    Top
\*!------------------------------------*/
.drawer--top .drawer-nav {
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: top .6s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  transition: top .6s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
}

.drawer--top.drawer-open .drawer-nav {
  top: 0;
}

.drawer--top .drawer-hamburger,
.drawer--top.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger {
  right: 0;
}
/*!------------------------------------*\
    Left
\*!------------------------------------*/
.drawer--left .drawer-nav {
  left: -400px;
  -webkit-transition: left .6s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  transition: left .6s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
}

.drawer--left.drawer-open .drawer-nav,
.drawer--left .drawer-hamburger,
.drawer--left.drawer-open .drawer-navbar .drawer-hamburger {
  left: 0;
}

/* Close button */
.drawer--left.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger{
left: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  background: inherit;
}

.drawer--left.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger-icon::before, 
.drawer--left.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger-icon::after {
    color: #d7f8fd;
    background: #d7f8fd;
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES */



@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .drawer--left.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger{
        left: 85%;
    }
}



/*!------------------------------------*\
    Right
\*!------------------------------------*/
.drawer--right .drawer-nav {
  right: -16.25rem;
  -webkit-transition: right .6s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  transition: right .6s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
}

.drawer--right.drawer-open .drawer-nav,
.drawer--right .drawer-hamburger,
.drawer--right.drawer-open .drawer-navbar .drawer-hamburger {
  right: 0;
}

.drawer--right.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger {
  right: 16.25rem;
}
/*!------------------------------------*\
    Hamburger
\*!------------------------------------*/
.drawer-hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 104;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 2rem;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-right: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: .75rem;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.drawer-hamburger:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.drawer-hamburger-icon {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;

}

.drawer-hamburger-icon,
.drawer-hamburger-icon:before,
.drawer-hamburger-icon:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  background-color: #222;
}


.drawer-hamburger-icon:before,
.drawer-hamburger-icon:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  content: ' ';
}

.drawer-hamburger-icon:after {
  top: 10px;
}

.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger-icon {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger-icon:before,
.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger-icon:after {
  top: 0;
}

.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger-icon:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.drawer-open .drawer-hamburger-icon:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
/*!------------------------------------*\
    accessibility
\*!------------------------------------*/

/*!
 * Only display content to screen readers
 * See: http://a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-hide-content
 */
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

/*!
 * Use in conjunction with .sr-only to only display content when it's focused.
 * Useful for "Skip to main content" links; see http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20130905/G1
 * Credit: HTML5 Boilerplate
 */
.sr-only-focusable:active,
.sr-only-focusable:focus {
  position: static;
  overflow: visible;
  clip: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
/*!------------------------------------*\
    Sidebar
\*!------------------------------------*/
.drawer--sidebar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.drawer--sidebar .drawer-contents {
  background-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .drawer--sidebar .drawer-hamburger {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .drawer--sidebar .drawer-nav {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: none;
        -ms-transform: none;
            transform: none;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
  }

  /*! Left */
  .drawer--sidebar.drawer--left .drawer-nav {
    left: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  }

  .drawer--sidebar.drawer--left .drawer-contents {
    margin-left: 12.5rem;
  }

  /*! Right */
  .drawer--sidebar.drawer--right .drawer-nav {
    right: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  }

  .drawer--sidebar.drawer--right .drawer-contents {
    margin-right: 12.5rem;
  }

  /*! container */
  .drawer--sidebar .drawer-container {
    max-width: 48rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 75em) {
  .drawer--sidebar .drawer-nav {
    width: 16.25rem;
  }

  .drawer--sidebar.drawer--left .drawer-contents {
    margin-left: 16.25rem;
  }

  .drawer--sidebar.drawer--right .drawer-contents {
    margin-right: 16.25rem;
  }

  /*! container */
  .drawer--sidebar .drawer-container {
    max-width: 60rem;
  }
}
/*!------------------------------------*\
    Navbar
\*!------------------------------------*/
.drawer--navbarTopGutter {
  padding-top: 3.75rem;
}

.drawer-navbar .drawer-navbar-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.drawer-navbar {
  z-index: 102;
  top: 0;
}

/*! .drawer-navbar modifier */
.drawer-navbar--fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.drawer-navbar-header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 102;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 .75rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.drawer-navbar .drawer-brand {
  line-height: 3.75rem;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.drawer-navbar .drawer-brand:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.drawer-navbar .drawer-nav {
  padding-top: 3.75rem;
}

.drawer-navbar .drawer-menu {
  padding-bottom: 7.5rem;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .drawer-navbar {
    height: 3.75rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  .drawer-navbar .drawer-navbar-header {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }

  .drawer-navbar .drawer-menu--right {
    float: right;
  }

  .drawer-navbar .drawer-menu li {
    float: left;
  }

  .drawer-navbar .drawer-menu-item {
    line-height: 3.75rem;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  .drawer-navbar .drawer-hamburger {
    display: none;
  }

  .drawer-navbar .drawer-nav {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    width: auto;
    height: 3.75rem;
    padding-top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  .drawer-navbar .drawer-menu {
    padding: 0;
  }

  /*! dropdown */
  .drawer-navbar .drawer-dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16.25rem;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
  }

  .drawer-navbar .drawer-dropdown-menu-item {
    padding-left: .75rem;
  }
}
/*!------------------------------------*\
    Dropdown
\*!------------------------------------*/
.drawer-dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.drawer-dropdown-menu > li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.drawer-dropdown-menu-item {
  line-height: 3.75rem;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: .75rem;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
}

.drawer-dropdown-menu-item:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #555;
  background-color: transparent;
}

/*! open */
.drawer-dropdown.open > .drawer-dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

li.drawer-dropdown {
    padding: 0;
}

/*! drawer-caret */
.drawer-dropdown .drawer-caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease, -webkit-transform .2s ease;
  transition: opacity .2s ease, -webkit-transform .2s ease;
  transition: transform .2s ease, opacity .2s ease;
  transition: transform .2s ease, opacity .2s ease, -webkit-transform .2s ease;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 4px solid;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}

/*! open */
.drawer-dropdown.open .drawer-caret {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg);
}
/*!------------------------------------*\
    Container
\*!------------------------------------*/
.drawer-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .drawer-container {
    max-width: 60rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 75em) {
  .drawer-container {
    max-width: 70rem;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
!function (e) {
    "use strict";
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], e) : "object" == typeof exports ? module.exports = e(require("jquery")) : e(jQuery)
}
(function (e) {
    "use strict";
    var t = "drawer",
    n = "undefined" != typeof document.ontouchstart,
    s = {
        init : function (n) {
            return n = e.extend({
                    iscroll : {
                        mouseWheel : !0,
                        preventDefault : !1
                    },
                    showOverlay : !0
                }, n),
            s.settings = {
                state : !1,
                events : {
                    opened : "drawer.opened",
                    closed : "drawer.closed"
                },
                dropdownEvents : {
                    opened : "shown.bs.dropdown",
                    closed : "hidden.bs.dropdown"
                }
            },
            s.settings["class"] = e.extend({
                    nav : "drawer-nav",
                    toggle : "drawer-toggle",
                    overlay : "drawer-overlay",
                    open : "drawer-open",
                    close : "drawer-close",
                    dropdown : "drawer-dropdown"
                }, n["class"]),
            this.each(function () {
                var o = this,
                r = e(this),
                a = r.data(t);
                a || (n = e.extend({}, n), r.data(t, {
                        options : n
                    }), s.refresh.call(o), n.showOverlay && s.addOverlay.call(o), e("." + s.settings["class"].toggle).on("click." + t, function () {
                        return s.toggle.call(o),
                        o.iScroll.refresh()
                    }), e(window).resize(function () {
                        return s.close.call(o),
                        o.iScroll.refresh()
                    }), e("." + s.settings["class"].dropdown).on(s.settings.dropdownEvents.opened + " " + s.settings.dropdownEvents.closed, function () {
                        return o.iScroll.refresh()
                    }))
            })
        },
        refresh : function () {
            this.iScroll = new IScroll("." + s.settings["class"].nav, e(this).data(t).options.iscroll)
        },
        addOverlay : function () {
            var t = e(this),
            n = e("<div>").addClass(s.settings["class"].overlay + " " + s.settings["class"].toggle);
            return t.append(n)
        },
        toggle : function () {
            var e = this;
            return s.settings.state ? s.close.call(e) : s.open.call(e)
        },
        open : function () {
            var o = e(this);
            return n && o.on("touchmove." + t, function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
            }),
            o.removeClass(s.settings["class"].close).addClass(s.settings["class"].open).css({
                overflow : "hidden"
            }).drawerCallback(function () {
                s.settings.state = !0,
                o.trigger(s.settings.events.opened)
            })
        },
        close : function () {
            var o = e(this);
            return n && o.off("touchmove." + t),
            o.removeClass(s.settings["class"].open).addClass(s.settings["class"].close).css({
                overflow : "auto"
            }).drawerCallback(function () {
                s.settings.state = !1,
                o.trigger(s.settings.events.closed)
            })
        },
        destroy : function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                var n = e(this);
                e(window).off("." + t),
                n.removeData(t)
            })
        }
    };
    e.fn.drawerCallback = function (t) {
        var n = "transitionend webkitTransitionEnd";
        return this.each(function () {
            var s = e(this);
            s.on(n, function () {
                return s.off(n),
                t.call(this)
            })
        })
    },
    e.fn.drawer = function (n) {
        return s[n] ? s[n].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)) : "object" != typeof n && n ? void e.error("Method " + n + " does not exist on jQuery." + t) : s.init.apply(this, arguments)
    }
});
```

To see a live demo: http://git.blivesta.com/drawer/left/